# Issues hiding a Flash SWF object in Safari 5.1 on OSX 10.7 (It works fine with Safari 5.1 on 10.6)

Tags: safari, osx-lion, swfobject

I am using JS to hide and show a flash video object at various stages in a flow. The function works perfectly in all browsers including Safari 5.1 on OSX 10.6, but does not work on Safari 5.1.3, 5.1.4 and 5.1.5 on OSX 10.7. It repositions on the page but remains visible.

You can see the issue [here](http://www.test.launchpadrecruits.com/interviews/demo).

Any help really appreciated!

**Embed code:**

```
  var swfVersionStr="10.2.0";
  var xiSwfUrlStr="/video/expressInstall.swf";
  var flashvars={
    sToken:"#{@stream_name}",
    sSWFPath: "/video/Recorder.swf",
    sConfigPath: "#{current_recorder_config_file}"
  };
  var params={
    bgcolor:"#FFFFFF",
    allowfullscreen:"true",
    allownetworking:"all",
    allowscriptaccess:"always",
    base:".",
    devicefont:"false",
    menu:"false",
    play:"true",
    quality:"high",
    salign:"tl",
    scale:"showall",
    seamlesstabbing:"false",
    swliveconnect:"true",
    wmode:"window"
  };

  var attributes={
    id:"Recorder",
    name:"Recorder"
  };
  swfobject.embedSWF("/video/Recorder.swf", "flashContent", "384", "318", swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

**JS for Hide and Show:**

```
function hideVideo() {$('.step_video, #flashContent').css({visibility:'hidden', height:1})}

function showVideo() {$('.step_video, #flashContent').css({visibility:'visible', height:'auto'})}
```

Comment: Just a quick guess: It should be `height:'1px'` - numeric values without units for positioning often cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Already had this bug before you shouldn't hide it, it's a bug with flash.
My workaround was :

```
  position: absolute;
  left: -5000px;
```